# Get specific part from string

Tags: php, string

I have string like this:
My code is:

```
$html = new DOMDocument();


    $html->loadHTML($message);
    $items = $html->getElementsByTagName('div');
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $headline = array();

        if($item->childNodes->length) {
            foreach($item->childNodes as $i) {
                $headline[$i->nodeName] = $i->nodeValue;
            }
        }

        $headlines[] = $headline;
    } 
    foreach ($headlines as $key => $value) {
    $quote =  $value['blockquote'];
    }.
print_r($quote);

output ="this is your message.
       Your Ticket ID = :68
       Response ID = :45check that if its not contains any error."
```

I want to get the `Ticket ID =:68` and `Response id =:45`.

when i print the blockquote i get the above text.now i want to get my ticket id and response id but don't know how  ?

Comment: take a look at regular expressions, that should help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this with regular expressions

```
$var ="this is your message.
   Your Ticket ID = :68
   Response ID = :45check that if its not contains any error.";

$match = array();    
$ticketID = '';
$responseID = '';

preg_match('/Your Ticket ID = :([0-9]+)/', $var, $match);
if(count($match) > 0) {
    $ticketID = $match[0];
}
preg_match('/Response ID = :([0-9]+)/', $var, $match);
if(count($match) > 0) {
    $responseID = $match[0];
}

var_dump($ticketID, $responseID);
```

Outputs:

```
string 'Your Ticket ID = :68' (length=20)
string 'Response ID = :45' (length=17)
```

Comment: wow your code works great.thanks.i am confused about the matching part.

Comment: You just pass a regular expression and everything which matches it goes to *$match*.

Comment: hmm you are right.the problem is with me , i never used the preg match function.